# Assigning different random number to each slot in an array

Tags: python, numpy, random

Here is my code:

```
mut1 = np.zeros((100, 52))
mutate = lambda mut1 : mut1 + (np.random.uniform(0, 1) > 0.5) * np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1)
mut1 = mutate(mut1)
print(mut1)

[[-0.02017634 -0.02017634 -0.02017634 ... -0.02017634 -0.02017634
  -0.02017634]
 [-0.02017634 -0.02017634 -0.02017634 ... -0.02017634 -0.02017634
  -0.02017634]
 [-0.02017634 -0.02017634 -0.02017634 ... -0.02017634 -0.02017634
  -0.02017634]
 ...
 [-0.02017634 -0.02017634 -0.02017634 ... -0.02017634 -0.02017634
  -0.02017634]
 [-0.02017634 -0.02017634 -0.02017634 ... -0.02017634 -0.02017634
  -0.02017634]
 [-0.02017634 -0.02017634 -0.02017634 ... -0.02017634 -0.02017634
  -0.02017634]]
```

THe problem is that each element in my `mut1` array gets the same mutation.

Comment: Any reason for a lambda here? Is there any reason you can't do something like: `mut1 + =(np.random.uniform(0,1,mut1.shape) > 0.5) * np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,mut1.shape)` ?

Comment: oops, tried to overcomplicate it. thanks vm

Comment: This happens because ```(np.random.uniform(0,1) > 0.5) * np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1)```   will be broadcasted in order to add to the mut1 array. Since it's just a single value that has been broadcasted, you are going to see the same mutation through out the mut1 array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43788033/6361531

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the random mutation to the entire array, which is the reason that all the elements are the same. You need to do this per element:

```
mut1 = np.zeros((100,52))
mutate = lambda x : x + (np.random.uniform(0,1) > 0.5) * np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1)
mutator = np.vectorize(mutate)
mutator(mut1)
print(mut1)
```

Comment: Another option instead of `np.vectorize` (which does no magic) is to specify the shape of the random arrays based on `x`, as written in [a comment on OP's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520914/creating-a-mutation-using-lambda-but-a-different-random-number-is-used-everyti#comment110566981_62520914).

Comment: Your diagnosis is spot-on, but `vectorize` is almost never the best option in numpy, as it's just a glorified python loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate at least as many numbers as you want to fill slots. The simple method would be to use `np.where`, and select from either the original array or the mutation based on the mask:

```
mut1 = np.where(np.random.randint(2, size=mut1.shape, dtype=bool),
                np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=mut1.shape), mut1)
```

This is a little wasteful because it generates random numbers for the entire array, not just the masked portion. You can mitigate that by setting the masked portion directly.

```
mask = np.random.randint(2, size=mut1.shape, dtype=bool)
count = np.count_nonzero(mask)
mut1[mask] = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=count)
```

Notes:

- If you don't generate separate values for each updated element, the single value will be broadcasted to all of them.
- A lambda is functionally identical to a function. You don't need to use it here at all.
- There is no need to threshold a floating point array to get the mask in this particular case, since you can generate booleans directly. For irrational ratios, thresholding would be easier though.